# "Google Maps for ExpressionEngine" field validation with Zoo Visitor Update Form

Tags: custom-fields, google-maps-for-ee, validation, channel-fields

I am using [Google Maps for ExpressionEngine](https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps/fieldtype) field type with [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/update.html) update member entry form. But I couldn't make this field type as `Required`.

I tried by having "Is this a required field?" as "Yes" from field setting and/or validation rule `rules:field_name="required"` but no luck.

Could anyone please suggest how can I validate Google Map field.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting "minimum points" to something other than 0? You can find it in the field settings of your Google Maps channel field.

Comment: Thanks Isabel, I 'll try it but not sure if its related to validation Google Map filed as `required`.

Comment: In theory, if you instruct the fieldtype that the minimum number of points is 1 (or more), when you submit the channel form with 0 points it should give you an error, which should be the behavior you want to have when you set a field to required.

Comment: It doesn't seem working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something very similar, but instead of using a map fieldtype I chose to just make the native EE grid custom field to hold the address. This way you can easily make the fields required. See example below.

```
{my_address}
    {my_address:street_address_1} 
    {my_address:street_address_2} 
    {my_address:city} 
    {my_address:state} 
    {my_address:zip}
{/my_address}
```

I'm using Zoo Visitor, but for maps I'm using [Gmaps](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps). In my template I can use this information within the gmaps tag to bring in the address. I'm sure that Google Maps for ExpressionEngine has a similar tag.

Cheers!
jules